# Inform7: How to center text?

Tags: centering, inform7

Looking at the documentation for Inform7, which is a bit scattered, I found some examples of centering text with:

```
carryout someaction:
     say paragraph break;
     center "Some text to be centered";
```

But this formulation doesn't seem to work nor does [center].

How do I center text with Inform7? For "say"? For a room description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `center` phrase is defined in the built-in extension Basic Screen Effects by Emily Short which you need to include first. Example [369](http://inform7.com/learn/man/ex125.html#e125) shows how it works.

Centering a `say` phrase uses `center` as in your example. Unfortunately room descriptions are often so long that Inform can't handle them correctly; if the text to be centered is longer than one line it will be left-justified.

Comment: And how do I include the screen effects? I'd seen the library but I thought they were included. "Include Basic Screen Effects by Emily Short."?